# Skip to next iteration in a (Typescript) .forEach loop with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, typescript, foreach, electron, settimeout

I have an array containing the urls of an image and want to change the src of an `img` tag every 10 seconds. 
I iterate over the array with a `forEach`, the callback contains a `setTimeout` which periodically calls the function (`replaceImage`) that does DOM manipulation as follows:

```
const el = document.querySelector('img');
images.forEach((obj: Image, index: number) => {
    timer = window.setTimeout(() => {
        replaceImage(el, obj);
    }, index * 10000);
});
```

However, if a button is clicked, I want the loop to **not** wait for the timeout and skip to the next iteration—i.e., replace the image straight away.

I naively thought this could be done by `clearTimeout(timer)` on button click.

(As a side note, this above is happening in a renderer process of an Electron app).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hold an array of the image links you like to show up (e.g. `diashow[url1, url2, ...]`. When a function filled up the array it calls `setTimeout(()=> nextPicture(el, diashow))`. The method `nextPicture(el, diashow)` calls something like

```
const picture = diashow.shift();

if(picture) {
    el.url = picture;
    this.timeHandle = setTimeout(()=>nextPicture(el, diashow), 10000);
}
```

In that case your picture will periodically replaced. In your button method you can then also call `el.url = diashow.shift()` and maybe reset the timer by calling clear and set immediately.

Comment: Hi Oliver, sorry but I am not sure I understood what you mean by "When a function filled up the array it calls setTimeout(() => nextPicture(el, diashow)"

Comment: @dfucci: your question starts with: "I have an array containing the urls of an image and...". So from where did you get that array? That thing, that delivers, creates that array has to start the slideshow by doing the first call to `setTimeout()`. After that the method will take care to call itself if any further pictures are available.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want. Note: this will continuously rotate through the images, i.e. after the last, the first will be loaded - not sure if you want that

```
const el = document.querySelector('img');

let index = 0;
let interval;

const go = () => {
    const doImage = () => {
        replaceImage(el, img[index]);
        index = (index + 1) % images.length;
    };
    if (interval) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(doImage, 10000);
    doImage();
}
go();
```

calling `go()` on the button click will

1. immediately load the next image; and
2. restart the interval - therefore the new image will stay for 10 seconds